# Regular expression to cancel event if incorrect

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a regular expression in c# winforms. I have it to identify whether if the format is correct or not. If correct it'll continue with saving but if in correct it will show its validation and cancel the saving event.

***Validating code***

```
private void emailTxt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string pattern = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\\.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(emailTxt.Text, pattern))
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        errorEmail.SetError(emailTxt, "Incorrect Format Try... email@email.com");
        CancelBtn.Enabled = true;              
    }
}
```

***Save code***

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SQL Connection and SQL for inserting a new admin
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            if (ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
            {
                try
                {
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO Admin (Admin_Username, Admin_FName, Admin_SName, Admin_Email, Admin_Password) " + "VALUES (@adminName, @adminFirstname, @adminSurname, @adminEmail, @adminPassword);";

                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminName", usernameTxt.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminFirstname", firstnameTxt.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminSurname", surnameTxt.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminEmail", emailTxt.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminPassword", passwordTxt.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Admin Successfully Added!");

                    this.Close();

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

It is stating that it's incorrect format but it's continuing to save the event even when the formatting is incorrect.

Comment: The error is somewhere else and we can not see that. Whete is the saving code?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i have updated the code above with my save code.

Comment: Can you show `validateChildren` method

Comment: @Valentin above is all the code.

Comment: @DonaldBury, thetre should be ValidateChildren method. You should show it.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri but i do not have one. This is odd.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri ValidateChildren is a built-in form function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it to work by nesting it with in the function already validating whether its empty or not. This seems to work.

```
private void emailTxt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailTxt.Text))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        errorEmail.SetError(emailTxt, "Email is Empty!");
        CancelBtn.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        string email = emailTxt.Text;
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
        Match match = regex.Match(email);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            errorEmail.SetError(emailTxt, "Incorrect Format Try... email@email.com");
            CancelBtn.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }                                
    }
}
```